# set cursor position of edittext in center...!

Tags: android, xml

I know this question asked many times. But none of examples work for me.
I want to set cursor position in the center through XML file.
how can I do that?? 
My current cursor position display in following figure.

My XML file code is following

.XML file

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/sigupDisplayName"
            style="@style/editTextStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"

            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="@string/display_name" >

            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: check my answer hope it will help you hint with edit text

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found now what is main problem...
Problem is in the API level..

I change API level of my program. 
Below API 15, cursor is set in the center in my application..
From API 16, cursor position set to start of the Hint text...!!!

Answer (score 1):

try below edittext instead of yours. This will work for you

```
   <EditText android:id="@+id/sigupDisplayName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/display_name" >
```

**EDIT** Remove Hint and you will see it in middle of the editText.

Comment: You need to remove Hint from it. and it will work. Edition will start from starting of hint.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
your_edit_text.setText("bla-bla-bla");
int position = your_edit_text.length();
Editable text = your_edit_text.getText();
Selection.setSelection(text, position / 2);
```

Or this:

`your_edit_text.setSelection(position / 2)`

Try this if upper doesn`t work:

```
your_edit_text.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            your_edit_text.setSelection(your_edit_text.getText().length() / 2);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Or this:

yourEditText.requestFocus(Your_Text.length() / 2);

Comment: I want to set default cursor position in the center. and "Display Name ","Email"... all 4 is android:hint.. I want to set cursor position in center in HINT...

Comment: So u whant to set gravity of hint to center? if yes, try to do this : `yourEditText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER); `

Comment: current my edit text look like this....   
|Display Name...
but I want to display like following..
Display| Name

Assume that "|" is cursor ...

Comment: I dont understand why this solutin is incorrect. You initialize and then setSelection.

Comment: You are not wrong but I want to set cursor position using XML way. but Now I found that what is the main problem.. See my Answer..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/edittext_style"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/sigupDisplayName"
        style="@style/editTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:hint="@string/display_name" >

    </EditText>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: change Edit Text WIdth with wrap_content

Answer (score 0):

Use TextInputLayout it will work fine with a hint.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Email"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```